# Библиотека JS, по типу noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

Делаю калькулятор резки труб, и нужна библиотека (не хочется изобретать велосипед), отмечать места реза.

Нашел [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) и [ionRangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/), проблема в динамическом добавлении отметок реза (пинов). Во второй библиотеке их вообще может быть только 1 или 2, а в первой нет методов добавления, вариант на каждый новый пин пересобирать полоску с пинами, не хороший.

На сайте [cssgradient.io](https://cssgradient.io/), с точки зрения механики, то что нужно, посмотрев по коду пришел к выводу что ребята писали сами.